# Embedding "Addicting Games" Flash Games on Website

Tags: html, flash, web, embed

When I embed "addicting games" Flash games on my website, they just come up white and say the movie isn't loaded. Addicting Games provides an easy embed link to just copy to your website but it isn't working on any of my computers, browsers, etc...

Here is the link http://www.zentenialgames.com/infectionator.html.

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=10,0,0,0"
id="gameObject" width="700" height="500"><param name="movie"
value="/newGames/strategy-games/infectionator/infectionator_w.swf"/><param
name="menu" value="false"/><param name="allowscriptaccess"
value="samedomain"/><param name="allownetworking" value="all"/><embed
src="/newGames/strategy-games/infectionator/infectionator_w.swf"
width="700" height="500" menu="false"  allowscriptaccess="samedomain"
allownetworking="all" name="gameObject"
type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></embed></object><span
style="font-size:11px;"><br/><a href=""
style="font-size:11px;">Games</a>:<a
href="http://www.addictinggames.com/strategy-games/index.jsp"
style="font-size:11px;">Play Strategy Games on
AddictingGames</a><br/><a
href="http://www.addictinggames.com/legal/terms-use.jsp"
style="font-size:11px;">Terms of Use</a> | <a
href="http://www.addictinggames.com/legal/copyright.jsp"
style="font-size:11px;">© 2012 Atom Entertainment, Inc., a subsidiary
of Viacom International Inc. All Rights Reserved.</a></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with the following

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=10,0,0,0" id="gameObject" width="700" height="500"><param name="movie" value="/newGames/strategy-games/infectionator/infectionator_w.swf"/><param name="menu" value="false"/><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="samedomain"/><param name="allownetworking" value="all"/><embed src="/newGames/strategy-games/infectionator/infectionator_w.swf" width="700" height="500" menu="false"  allowscriptaccess="samedomain" allownetworking="all" name="gameObject" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></embed></object><span style="font-size:11px;"><br/><a href="" style="font-size:11px;">Games</a>:<a href="http://www.addictinggames.com/strategy-games/index.jsp" style="font-size:11px;">Play Strategy Games on AddictingGames</a><br/><a href="http://www.addictinggames.com/legal/terms-use.jsp" style="font-size:11px;">Terms of Use</a> | <a href="http://www.addictinggames.com/legal/copyright.jsp" style="font-size:11px;">&copy; 2012 Atom Entertainment, Inc., a subsidiary of Viacom International Inc. All Rights Reserved.</a></span>
```

You were missing the 'http://addictinggames.com/' in 2 places in your code.

One was 'value="/newGames/strategy-games/infectionator/infectionator_w.swf"'

other spot was 'src="/newGames/strategy-games/infectionator/infectionator_w.swf"'

Comment: I made the replacement that you said, but it still isn't working if you check the link, I updated it.

Comment: The link is dead now.